# How to pass List's content to another Activity Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to pass List from one Activity to another. As I checked by Logs, in FindAllPairsEasyActivity it puts player_points to the list but I can't read it in ProgressActivity.

What I want is to display a set of points as ListView because there are few games.

FindAllPairsEasyActivity.java (only two methods):

```
public class FindAllPairsEasyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 ArrayList<Integer> findAllPairsList = new ArrayList<>(); 
...

 public void saveScore() {
        //Log.i("info","saveScore w find all pairs easy");
        SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences(usernameView.getText().toString(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        int totalScore = preferences.getInt("totalScore",0);
        totalScore = totalScore + player_points;
        editor.putInt("rts_score",player_points);
        findAllPairsList.add(player_points);
        //Log.i("d","FindAllPairsEasy findAllPairsList: " + findAllPairsList);
        editor.putInt("total_score",totalScore);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getList() {
        return findAllPairsList;
    }
```

ProgressActivity.java:

```
public class ProgressActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ListView list;
    TextView usernameView, myProgressView, totalScoreView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_progress);

        totalScoreView = findViewById(R.id.totalScoreView);
        myProgressView = findViewById(R.id.myProgressView);

        //List <Integer> findAllPairsList = findAllPairsEasyActivity.getList();

        AssetManager am = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
        Typeface logoFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(am, String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "fonts/%s","FjallaOne-Regular.ttf"));
        Typeface myProgressFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(am, String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "fonts/%s","Montserrat-Regular.ttf"));
        myProgressView.setTypeface(logoFont);
        myProgressView.setText("My Progress");

        list =  findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        String user = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
        usernameView = findViewById(R.id.username_progress);
        usernameView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        usernameView.setText("" + user);

        //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_progress,R.id.listView1,cars);

        SharedPreferences preferences =  this.getSharedPreferences(usernameView.getText().toString(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int rts_score = preferences.getInt("rts_score",0);
        int mc_score = preferences.getInt("mc_score",0);
        int g_score = preferences.getInt("g_score",0);
        int ftt_score = preferences.getInt("ftt_score",0);

        int total_score = rts_score + mc_score + g_score + ftt_score;

        FindAllPairsEasyActivity findAllPairsEasyActivity = new FindAllPairsEasyActivity();
        list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,findAllPairsEasyActivity.getList()));


        Log.i("list","findAllPairsList content: " + findAllPairsEasyActivity.getList().size());

        totalScoreView.setTypeface(logoFont);
        totalScoreView.setText("Total score: " + total_score);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You will have to implement on onClickListener over the list adapter. Then using that, you will have to fetch the clicked data (via position). Once you have the desired data, you can pass it using intent to another activity

Comment: which activity occurs first `ProgressActivity` or `FindAllPairsEasyActivity` ? Might your sharedpreference is not saved because of that

Comment: First is  `FindAllPairsEasyActivity` (it is one of games), then user can check his points in `ProgressActivity`.

Comment: Did you check if your sharedpreference saves the data of user ?

Comment: @AtishAgrawal What do you mean by that?

Comment: Confirm if your sharedpreference is holding data or not.

Comment: you are inserting only rts_score,total_score in preference. But getting lot in ProgressActivity like mc_score,g_score etc

Answer (score 0):

Is it really necessary to save data in `SharedPreference`, if the motive is just sending data?

Why not just use `putExtra` to send data and use `getSerializableExtra` to get data?

Activity FindAllPairsEasyActivity:

```
ArrayList<Integer> findAllPairsList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
intent.putExtra("my_list", findAllPairsList);
startActivity(intent);
```

Activity ProgressActivity:

```
ArrayList<Integer> findAllPairsList = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("my_list");
```

Comment: Thank you Darvesh for your idea. Problem is already solved so everyone who helped, thank you :)

Comment: Or you can use Gson, it's simple and powerful, a library any android developer must have to know. https://github.com/google/gson